# How can I check the current date in a template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object with a timestamp in my component.

What I try to do is to check the timestamp at runtime in the template.
for example to show the user online status of a member.. if online I show a green dot, else it should switch to a red dot live during runtime.

```
<div class="show_member_line">
  {{member.membername}} 
  <div *ngIf="member.lastactivity > ( !!!new Date().getTime()!!! - 120 )" class="status_online"></div>
  <div *ngIf="member.lastactivity < ( !!!new Date().getTime()!!! - 120 )" class="status_offline"></div>
</div>
```

anybody have an idea? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better approach in my opinion would be to create a timer in your component like

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

private timerSubscription: any = null;
private lastActivityTime: Date;

ngOnInit(){
    let timer = Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
    this.timerSubscription = timer.subscribe((t:any) => {
        this.timerExecuted();
    });
}    

private timerExecuted(): void {
     var currentDate = new Date();
     currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 2);  //subtract 2 hours or 120 minutes from current date
     this.lastActivityTime = currentDate;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    //unsubscribe the subscription in ngDestroy
    if (this.timerSubscription != null)
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

lastActivityTime will be updated after each second and you can use it for comparison more easily in your template like

```
<div class="show_member_line">
  {{member.membername}} 
  <div *ngIf="member.lastactivity > lastActivityTime" class="status_online"></div>
  <div *ngIf="member.lastactivity < lastActivityTime" class="status_offline"></div>
</div>
```